# SQL Join using a join table from rails

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So, I am not sure what the best way to do a join for these tables was. I want to use a JOIN because I believe it is faster than bring all three of the tables in on FROM. So, if i have three tables...

```
Table1
--id
--data

Table2
--id
--data

Table1_Table2
--table1_id
--table2_id
```

How can I do a join for this data using the join table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning all tables in the `FROM` clause is also a join, implicit one. It is not recommended to use it as it might lead to a Cartesian product of the tables involved in case you'll forget to add predicates in the `WHERE` clause.

Have a look on the [Wikipedia JOIN article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and also at this [very nice blogpost](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) about joins by Jeff Atwood.

I think that you're interested in the `INNER JOIN` between the tables, although other variants exists. Try this:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table1_Table2 tt ON t1.id = tt.table1_id
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = tt.table2_id;
```

I skipped Table1_Table2 columns from the select list, as there's nothing special there.

Answer (score 0):

While the above solution works, you might want to give the rails-way solution a try

Since you require a join table with only the primary keys of the participating tables, you can loop into [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) association. It does the same as the SQL query behind the scenes and is a neater solution. You can also look into **has_many through** association(also explained in the linked railscasts) if you want to add more columns to the join table.